# How to build a Line chart on g2plot so that the series are built from numeric fields

Tags: antv, g2plot

guys!
I'm woking with library using full api of https://g2plot.antv.antgroup.com/en/api/plots/line
(https://consta.design/libs/charts/components-line-stable/dev)

The data looks like an array of similar objects

```
{category: 'Cat1', sum: 2681, avg: 8.457413249211356}
{category: 'Cat2', sum: 44990, avg: 120.94086021505376}
{category: 'Cat3', sum: 20933, avg: 45.30952380952381}
```

How can I build a Line chart, category on the X axis, values on the Y axis, so that I get 2 series: one for sum, the second for avg?
I would be grateful for any advice.

I only get two separate line chart so far for every value field. Sad

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.